# Как скопировать второе слово из столбца одной таблицы в столбец другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как скопировать второе слово из столбца(pagetitle) таблицы 1 (content) в столбец(tags) таблицы 2 (product), при том что у них общий id

Разбираем скрин: Нужно в таблице 1 (content) из столбца pagetitle скопировать 2-е слово и записать его в таблицу 2 (product) в столбец tags. В обеих таблицах общим является столбец ID.

Так получается выбрать 2-е слово:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pagetitle,
   CASE
       WHEN INSTR( pagetitle, ' ' ) = 0
       THEN
           ''
       ELSE
           SUBSTRING(
               SUBSTRING( pagetitle, LOCATE(' ', pagetitle) + 1),
               1,
               LOCATE( ' ', CONCAT(SUBSTRING( pagetitle, LOCATE(' ', pagetitle) + 1), ' ') ) - 1
           )
   END FROM `content`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: давайте с примером данных, какие у вас есть. Ибо ваше описание не шибко понятно

Answer (score 0):

```
update products
  set tags = ( select ... с выборкой второго слова ... where id = products.id)
```

Comment: При таком вызове выдает ошибку  #1241 - Операнд должен содержать 1 колонок

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `products` SET `tags` = concat('["', (

SELECT

SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING( pagetitle, LOCATE(' ', pagetitle) + 1),1,
LOCATE( ' ', SUBSTRING( pagetitle, LOCATE(' ', pagetitle) + 1) ) - 1
)

FROM `content` WHERE id = products.id), '"]')